# Where to place delegate definitions

Tags: c#, delegates

Every time I have made a delegate definition, I think about where to put it in a project.

Do I put it in the file with the class consuming the delegate? I would think NO, as it could be interesting for other classes to use the same delegate.

Do I put it in the file with the delegate object? I would think NO, as the general idea usually is, that several diferent classes and/or methods can be used for that.

Do I put it in a file of its own ? I would think NO because - well - it just seems plain silly to have a one line file in projects that potentially holds hundreds if not thousands of files.

Do I collect delegates in larger utility type files ? Hmmmm.... don't like.

So what do I do ?

Comment: Like every other piece of code, you put them wherever is appropriate for the current scenario. You need to narrow your question down.

Comment: @AntP. I don't know if I can narrow it down. My problem is that there never seems an appropriate place to put the delegate definition.

Comment: With `Action` and `Func` available I rarely need to declare custom delegates.